# How to Disable OK button when there is a text change in Editbox in MFC

Tags: mfc

How to Disable OK button when there is a text change in Editbox control?

When the following code was used,it results in an exception

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(LockingInfo, CDialog) 
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(LockingInfo)
   ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_INFO,OnEnChangeEdit1)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP 
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void LockingInfo::OnEnChangeEdit1()
{
  GetDlgItem(IDOK)->EnableWindow(FALSE);
}
```

and the exception is:

"Access violation reading location..." in line ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd) || (m_pCtrlSite != NULL)); of function CWnd::EnableWindow(BOOL bEnable) in winnocc.cpp

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong in the code you show. Please edit your question and show us the dialog definition extracted from the .rc file. Probably there is no control with the id of IDOK in the dialog. You should add `ASSERT(GetDlgItem(IDOK) != NULL);` at the beginning of `OnEnChangeEdit1`.

Comment: If I take a regular CDialog and use it in OnInitDialog()  the same way:GetDlgItem(IDOK)->EnableWindow(FALSE); it works fine.The OK button gets disabled.So it is something else that is being missed out

Comment: Without more information nobody can help.

Comment: I think the problem you have may be triggered because the code is fired before the complete instantiation of the form. If you don't have an `OnInitDialog` (or similar) method, implement it and put two breakpoints, one in it and another in your method. Then you can conclude if your method it is being called before creation. If it is the case you can condition your method with `If(GetDlgItem(IDOK)->GetSafeHwnd())`

Comment: I agree with @sergiol.

Comment: @sergiol on the other hand how could `OnEnChangeEdit1` get triggered before the dialog's window is fully initialized? We really need to see more code.

Comment: @sergiol. Yes,the method OnEnChangeEdit1()  it is being called before the OnInitDialog().

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Nancy could put a breakpoint on the method and look to the call stack to see who is responsible for calling it.

Comment: @Nancy, so you have the answer to your problem. The dialog window does not exist before `OnInitDialog` is called, therefore `GetDlgItem(IDOK)` is called on an inexistent window and returns `NULL`. It shouldn't be too hard to find out who calls `OnEnChangeEdit1`.

Comment: @sergiol. thanks! solved the problem

Comment: What solved the problem?

Comment: the method was being called before the dialogue window was fully initialized.